# Calling startActivity function on menu crashes the app

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-activity

I'm setting up a project that will receive details from the user, insert it to the SQLite DB and will show the information that was given by the user on the Second Activity's ListView.

I tried many tutorials and suggesting on the internet, tried ActivityForResult, tried not using Switch but still, nothing seems to work.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.SecondActivity:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.credits:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "some text ;)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }

    return true;

}
```

I expect it to run the second activity. But it keeps on crashing when I try switching between activities

Comment: Please add the logcat of this crash.

Comment: Did you add `SecondActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes it is on the .xml file

Comment: In `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, did you add something like, for example, starting with `<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"`?

Comment: Then could you add the logcat or stacktrace? You can find it in the bottom of Android Studio. When a crash happens, there will be a stacktrace showing what the problem is.

Comment: Show the logcat. Maybe the question is in SecondActivity instead of this jumping.

Comment: Watch the .xml file on : https://pastebin.com/r5frQx8R . The build run: https://pastebin.com/Vt0ZyhAn . What about the logcat? isn't it a bit long? Should I upload it?

Comment: There is the logcat: https://pastebin.com/WA8agt5w . The whole run + crash.

Comment: Yes, the logcat shows that there is a problem in your `SecondActivity.java`. In line 24, there is a call `something.query()`, where `something`, a `SQLiteDatabase`, is declared but not assigned.

Comment: Here's my SecondActivity.class https://pastebin.com/U9ss6wiA it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Enough for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 case R.id.SecondActivity:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
```

you might have problem in Second ativity check if it is exist or not in AndroidManifest.xml

or in intent calling if it is not fragment use Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);

Answer (score -1):

In your [`SecondActivity`](https://pastebin.com/U9ss6wiA), line 24:

```
Cursor getUserData=db.query(HelperDB.TABLE_USER,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

However, at this time (during initialization of `SecondActivity`), the variable `db` is declared (line 21) but not assigned (it is assigned **too late**, in `onCreate()` in line 33). Note that `<init>` of a class is far earlier than calling this `onCreate()`.

So move these two `Cursor` after line 33 (and, maybe, between line 33 and 34) will solve this issue.

Comment: @aslox What do you mean by "doesn't solve issue"? Do the stacktrace (line 35 to 59 in [run data](https://pastebin.com/Vt0ZyhAn)) **still** the same?

Comment: I _guess_ the new question is generated from the too-early `db.close()`.

Comment: I tried moving lines 24,25 to 34,35 (inside the onCreate function) that didn't work as well. watch the new run data: https://pastebin.com/M1ft5uSR

Comment: @asslox Yes, read line 110 and 115 in the new run data, you should remove the `db.close()` line, or, put it in the very bottom, for example at the end of `onCreate()` block.